# How can I condition the execution of my code on a date without indenting all my code?

Tags: python, date, datetime, automation

I have a Python script of 683 lines which is executed everyday by an ETL tool and I want it to be run just on certain days (Mondays) without having to configure the condition on the ETL tool. All the code has no objects, nor functions. I know that I could make:

```
if date.today().weekday() == 1: 
   all code
```

Or following the previous reasoning, make functions, or objects, but I do not want to indent all the lines, so I was wondering if there is something like this:

```
if date.today().weekday() == 1: 
   go to line X
else:
  go to the end/exit/go to line X
```

I have searched about pointers in Python but since Python allows object-oriented programming, there is no such feature.

So, is there any chance that I do not have to indent all my code for making what I want?

Comment: Indentation is how python distinguishes code blocks, so either way *something* will have to be indented.

Comment: I believe you can select a whole chunk of code and then simply press "TAB" key in an IDE to indent the chunk easily

Comment: No, Python doesn't have a `goto`. You could put "all code" in a function and call it conditional, but that would still involve indenting all it to put it in a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just exit the script immediately if it's not the correct date:

```
if date.today().weekday() != 1:
    sys.exit()
# rest of code here
```